# White Bar appearing at bottom of each view controller in storyboard but doesn't affect when ran

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

In my storyboard view these white bars appeared at the bottom of every view. I can't remember what I did when they appeared, the only thing I can think of was that I tried to add a bar button but then deleted it, so maybe that created some sort of bar. However the bar doesn't show up when running the app in the simulator, it just has a visual in the storyboard.

Does anyone know what it is / why it appeared? and also how can I get rid of it. I got rid of a few by changing the view heights and then changing them back, but when trying to do the same in the first view when I clicked the white bar they all appeared again on every view.

Also, I've noticed some are within the view and some are an extension.

[image: White bars on bottom of each view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by adding a bar button item and then removing it. The fix is pretty easy though. Go to your storyboard and select the View Controller having the issue.

[image]

You will then want to go to the Utility area on the right side of your screen. You will see **Bottom Bar = Translucent Toolbar**. Change that to None and you're good to go.

[image]

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thanks a lot, I knew it would be something simple like that!